# How to get the total score using SUM in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I'm getting 0 total score with my calculation below, could someone please assist on it. Thanks.
The $Total_personal_score is getting 0, I believe there is some issue with the code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Enumerations\ApprovalStatus;
use App\Enumerations\Status;
use App\Models\Objective;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;


class SummaryExport implements FromView
{
    public function view(): View
    {
        $users = User::where('status', 1)->get();

        $results = [];
        foreach($users as $key => $user) {
            $results[$key]['name'] = $user->name;
            $results[$key]['email'] = $user->email;
            $results[$key]['department'] = $user->department;
            $results[$key]['country'] = $user->country;
            $total_personal_score = Objective::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('year', $user->year)->sum('personal_score');
            $objective = Objective::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('year', date('Y'))->first();

        }

        

        
        return view('reports.summary', [
            'results' => $results,
            'total_personal_score' => $total_personal_score
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: variable $total_personal_score will only store the score of last user as it is not storing the accumulative sum but overriding with the score of each user. And somehow score of last user is calculated 0. I think it should be $total_personal_score +=   Objective::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('year', $user->year)->sum('personal_score');

Also you need to share some more details like table schema and relation with user

Comment: @AfzalAli Bro, I think Giles Bennett is correct....

Comment: then you should add score in array as well  like this.
$results[$key]['score'] = Objective::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('year', $user->year)->sum('personal_score');
and no need to return total_personal score separately

Comment: @AfzalAli I'm getting 0 also for total personal score

Comment: no need to use that variable , you can use it as $results[$i]['score'] in blade file

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the $total_personal_score once it's been calculated.

Within your foreach($users.... loop you're putting the name, email, department, country into the results array, and return that at the end, but the $total_personal_score and $objective are not being put into the $results array.

That means that by the time you come to return your view, you are assigning $total_personal_score (which is the value from the last iteration of your users loop) and passing that through. So I suspect the last user in your collection has a value of 0 for their total personal score.

Comment: He is return $total_personal_score with view. He just need to use accumulative sum

Comment: @GilesBennett I think u are correct, could you please guide me what to do for that?

Comment: It depends what you want - do you want (a) the aggregate of each user's personal score? or (b) the aggregate of all users' personal scores, or (c) both?